# D3 Dragging + Zooming in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, zooming, drag

Is it possible to translate the following D3 snippet into "pure" ReactJS to avoid any interaction with the DOM from D3 (to let React handle it instead)?

```
// Dragging an SVG `g` element
d3Select(this.g)
  .call(
    d3Drag()
      .on('start', this.handleDragStarted)
      .on('drag', this.handleDragged)
      .on('end', this.handleDragEnded)
  );

// Zooming
d3Zoom()
  .on('start', this.handleZoomStart)
  .on('zoom', this.handleZoom)
  .on('end', this.handleZoom);
```

Comment: I've been looking into this for a while now too. The only thing I could find about this is this three year old blog post: http://browniefed.com/blog/react-art-zooming-and-dragging/. It might hold some promising clues though. I've got a d3 force layout in react which is draggable after render, but stops being draggable after a few seconds. Would you mind having a look at it? I wonder if it might be related to the fact that d3 handles the dragging and not React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941413/react-d3-force-layout-why-arent-the-circles-not-draggable-anymore-after-a-f

Comment: Interesting article, thanks for sharing!