# How to set D3's tick function for multiple force layouts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to render multiple D3 force layouts on a page. I managed to initially render the layouts, but only the last graphs' nodes can be dragged a few seconds after render.

I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941413/react-d3-force-layout-circles-not-draggable-anymore-a-few-seconds-after-ren) a while ago. The problem came up because `d3.drag()` and `.tick()` weren't pointing to the right `d3.forceSimulation`. They were pointing to another `d3.forceSimulation` I mistakenly declared in the global namespace.

This time around I have multiple `d3.forceSimulation` again, but that's because I do want to render multiple force layouts.

I tried to map over each force layout's dataset and call `d3.forceSimulation` and `tick()` with each set.

Now, should `tick()` be called only once for all the data? Or for each layout seperately? It seems as if tick keeps working for the last graph only. So how can tick be set for all `force.simulation`?

[A live example can be found be here](https://codepen.io/vialito/pen/ZoLmWR?editors=0110)

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Functions and variables
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var FORCE = (function(nsp) {

  var
    width = 1080,
    height = 250,
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),

    initForce = (nodes, links) => {
      nsp.force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(70))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(nsp.width / 5).y(nsp.height / 2))
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide([5]).iterations([5]));
    },

    enterNode = (selection) => {
      var circle = selection.select('circle')
        .attr("r", 25)
        .style("fill", 'tomato')
        .style("stroke", "bisque")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")

      selection.select('text')
        .style("fill", "honeydew")
        .style("font-weight", "600")
        .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .style("font-family", "cursive")
    },

    updateNode = (selection) => {
      selection
        .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x = Math.max(30, Math.min(width - 30, d.x));
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y = Math.max(30, Math.min(height - 30, d.y));
        })
    },

    enterLink = (selection) => {
      selection
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("stroke", "bisque")
    },

    updateLink = (selection) => {
      selection
        .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);
    },

    updateGraph = (selection) => {
      selection.selectAll('.node')
        .call(updateNode)
      selection.selectAll('.link')
        .call(updateLink);
    },

    dragStarted = (d) => {
      if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y
    },

    dragging = (d) => {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y
    },

    dragEnded = (d) => {
      if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null
    },

    drag = () => d3.selectAll('g.node')
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragging)
      .on("end", dragEnded)
    ),

    tick = (that) => {
      that.d3Graph = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that));
      nsp.force.on('tick', () => {
        that.d3Graph.call(updateGraph)
      });
    };

  nsp.width = width;
  nsp.height = height;
  nsp.enterNode = enterNode;
  nsp.updateNode = updateNode;
  nsp.enterLink = enterLink;
  nsp.updateLink = updateLink;
  nsp.updateGraph = updateGraph;
  nsp.initForce = initForce;
  nsp.dragStarted = dragStarted;
  nsp.dragging = dragging;
  nsp.dragEnded = dragEnded;
  nsp.drag = drag;
  nsp.tick = tick;

  return nsp

})(FORCE || {})

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// class App is the parent component of Link and Node
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [{
            name: "one",
            id: 65,
            nodes: [{
                "name": "fruit",
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "name": "apple",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "orange",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "banana",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            links: [{
                "source": 0,
                "target": 1,
                "lineID": 1
              },
              {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 2
              },
              {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 0,
                "lineID": 3
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "two",
            id: 66,
            nodes: [{
                "name": "Me",
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "name": "Jim",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "Bob",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Jen",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            links: [{
                "source": 0,
                "target": 1,
                "lineID": 1
              },
              {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 2
              },
              {
                "source": 1,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 3
              },
              {
                "source": 2,
                "target": 3,
                "lineID": 4
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const data = this.state.data;
      data.map(({
        nodes,
        links
      }) => (
        FORCE.initForce(nodes, links)
      ));
      FORCE.tick(this)
      FORCE.drag()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.nodes !== this.state.nodes || prevState.links !== this.state.links) {
        const data = this.state.data;
        data.map(({
          nodes,
          links
        }) => (
          FORCE.initForce(nodes, links)
        ));
        FORCE.tick(this)
        FORCE.drag()
      }
    }

    render() {
      const data = this.state.data;

      return (

        <
        div className = "result__container" >

        <
        h5 className = "result__header" > Data < /h5> {
        data.map(({
            name,
            id,
            nodes,
            links
          }) => ( <
            div className = "result__box"
            key = {
              id
            }
            value = {
              name
            } >
            <
            h5 className = "result__name" > {
              name
            } < /h5> <
            div className = {
              "container__graph"
            } >
            <
            svg className = "graph"
            width = {
              FORCE.width
            }
            height = {
              FORCE.height
            } >
            <
            g > {
              links.map((link) => {
                  return ( <
                    Link key = {
                      link.lineID
                    }
                    data = {
                      link
                    }
                    />);
                  })
              } <
              /g> <
              g > {
                nodes.map((node) => {
                    return ( <
                      Node data = {
                        node
                      }
                      label = {
                        node.label
                      }
                      key = {
                        node.id
                      }
                      />);
                    })
                } <
                /g> < /
                svg > <
                /div> < /
                div >
              ))
          } <
          /div>
        )
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////// Link component
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    class Link extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.d3Link = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
          .datum(this.props.data)
          .call(FORCE.enterLink);
      }

      componentDidUpdate() {
        this.d3Link.datum(this.props.data)
          .call(FORCE.updateLink);
      }

      render() {
        return ( <
          line className = 'link' / >
        );
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////// Node component
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    class Node extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.d3Node = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
          .datum(this.props.data)
          .call(FORCE.enterNode)
      }

      componentDidUpdate() {
        this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
          .call(FORCE.updateNode)
      }

      render() {
        return ( <
          g className = 'node' >
          <
          circle onClick = {
            this.props.addLink
          }
          /> <
          text > {
            this.props.data.name
          } < /text> < /
          g >
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.container__graph {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.result__header {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: cadetblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.result__name {
  background-color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: chocolate;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick answer to your question: you do need to use each individual `force.on('tick',...)` for each simulation, because the tick event doesn't fire after a period of inactivity. But your program is actually running into another problem that causes the other graphs to freeze.

### The Problem:

The main issue is that you're creating multiple different force simulations, but attaching the same handler to all of them:

```
  data.map(({
    nodes,
    links
  }) => (
    FORCE.initForce(nodes, links) // initializes multiple force simulations 
  ));
  FORCE.tick(this)
  FORCE.drag() // attaches only one handler to them all
```

When you look at the code, you can see that you're reassigning `nsp.force` for each graph so it's only referring to the last one:

```
initForce = (nodes, links) => {
  nsp.force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      ...
},
```

This becomes a problem with your drag handler, which changes the alphaTarget, which more or less tells `nsp.force` (which now refers only to the last graph) that it needs to continuing simulating and to restart the simulation:

```
dragStarted = (d) => {
  if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  // ...
},

dragEnded = (d) => {
  if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0);
  // ...
},
```

So the reason why every graph but the last stops moving after a few seconds is because those simulation think they are complete because they aren't rewoken with a drag event.

### A Solution:

As I'm sure you've encountered, it's tricky managing multiple force simulations as one big object. Since they seem to be independent, it makes more sense to create a separate instance for the force simulation for each graph. In the following code snippet, I've changed the object `FORCE`, to be constructor `Force`, that creates an instance of a force simulation, which we'll create multiple times, one for each graph.

I've also made `ForceGraph`, a React component to hold the graph and SVG, to separate out elements for each graph, and makes it easer for that force simulation to act on.

Here are the results:

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Functions and variables
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Force() {
  var width = 1080,
  height = 250,
  enterNode = (selection) => {
      var circle = selection.select('circle')
        .attr("r", 25)
        .style("fill", 'tomato' ) 
        .style("stroke", "bisque")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")

      selection.select('text')
        .style("fill", "honeydew")
        .style("font-weight", "600")
        .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .style("font-family", "cursive")
      },
  updateNode = (selection) => {
      selection
        .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(30, Math.min(width - 30, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(30, Math.min(height - 30, d.y)); })
    },

  enterLink = (selection) => {
    selection
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("stroke","bisque")
  },

  updateLink = (selection) => {
    selection
      .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);
  },

  updateGraph = (selection) => {
    selection.selectAll('.node')
      .call(updateNode)
    selection.selectAll('.link')
      .call(updateLink);
  },
  color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),
  nsp = {},
      
  initForce = (nodes, links) => {
    nsp.force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(70))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(nsp.width /2).y(nsp.height / 2))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide([5]).iterations([5]));
  },

  dragStarted = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y
  },

  dragging = (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y
  },
      
  dragEnded = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) nsp.force.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null
  },

  drag = (node) => {
    var d3Graph = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node)).select('svg');
    d3Graph.selectAll('g.node')
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragging)
      .on("end", dragEnded));
  },

  tick = (node) => {
    var d3Graph = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node)).select('svg');
    nsp.force.on('tick', () => {
      d3Graph.call(updateGraph)
    });
  };

  nsp.enterNode = enterNode;
  nsp.updateNode = updateNode;
  nsp.enterLink = enterLink;
  nsp.updateLink = updateLink;
  nsp.width = width;
  nsp.height = height;
  nsp.initForce = initForce;
  nsp.dragStarted = dragStarted;
  nsp.dragging = dragging;
  nsp.dragEnded = dragEnded;
  nsp.drag = drag;
  nsp.tick = tick;
  
  return nsp
  
}

class ForceGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = props.data;
        this.force = Force();
    }

    initGraph() {
        const data = this.data;
        this.force.initForce(data.nodes, data.links)
        this.force.tick(this)
        this.force.drag(this)

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initGraph();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // TBD
    }

    render() {
        const {name, id, nodes, links} = this.data;
        const force = this.force;
        return (
            <div className="result__box" key={id} value={name}>
                <h5 className="result__name">{name}</h5>
                <div className={"container__graph"}>
                <svg className="graph" width={force.width} height={force.height}>
                    <g>
                        {links.map((link) => {
                            return (
                                <Link
                                    key={link.lineID}
                                    data={link}
                                    force={force}
                                />);
                        })}
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        {nodes.map((node) => {
                            return (
                                <Node
                                    data={node}
                                    label={node.label}
                                    force={force}
                                    key={node.id}
                                />);
                        })}
                    </g>
                </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }


};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// class App is the parent component of Link and Node
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [{
            name: "one",
            id: 65,
            nodes: [{
                "name": "fruit",
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "name": "apple",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "orange",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "banana",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            links: [{
                "source": 0,
                "target": 1,
                "lineID": 1
              },
              {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 2
              },
              {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 0,
                "lineID": 3
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "two",
            id: 66,
            nodes: [{
                "name": "Me",
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "name": "Jim",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "Bob",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Jen",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            links: [{
                "source": 0,
                "target": 1,
                "lineID": 1
              },
              {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 2
              },
              {
                "source": 1,
                "target": 2,
                "lineID": 3
              },
              {
                "source": 2,
                "target": 3,
                "lineID": 4
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    
    render() {
        const data = this.state.data;
        return (
            <div className="result__container">
                <h5 className="result__header">Data</h5>
                {data.map((graphData) => (<ForceGraph data={graphData} key={graphData.id} />))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Link component
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Link extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.d3Link = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
        .datum(this.props.data)
        .call(this.props.force.enterLink);
    }
  
    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.d3Link.datum(this.props.data)
        .call(this.props.force.updateLink);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <line className='link' />
      );
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Node component
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Node extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.d3Node = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
        .datum(this.props.data)
        .call(this.props.force.enterNode)
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
        .call(this.props.force.updateNode)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <g className='node'>
          <circle onClick={this.props.addLink}/>
          <text>{this.props.data.name}</text>
        </g>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.container__graph {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.result__header {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: cadetblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.result__name {
  background-color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: chocolate;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update**: It looks like if you try to update the data for the charts, it runs into some snags. I tinkered with it a little bit and came up with this fiddle. It's not perfect, but it's a start: https://jsfiddle.net/4pyzL0tq/

Comment: That's incredible Steve. I haven't learned so much at once before. This took a lot of effort and I'm very grateful for that. Thank you for your beautiful example.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, Vincent; glad that I could help. I did notice that updating data on the chart looked like it wouldn't work. I've updated my answer with an example of an approach you might take. It's outside of the scope of this question, but you might find it useful.

Comment: Your're way ahead of me, that's really nice! It's possible to edit a single graph now. Displaying these different graphs on a result page is where I ran into this problem. I didn't get to the point where you might edit one of these graphs yet, but that would be really cool! The data is stored in- and comes from a databse. I had to create a new object from these props and set it to state in `App`. The props didn't let D3 mutate it. I've been trying to make something out of D3 for a long time already, I really like it. Such a big help really means a lot to me, thank you.